# Lambda function memory leak in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, lambda, transform, visual-leak-detector

A  lambda function fun is supposed to return an input vector multiplied with the value of a scalar function f evaluated at t. Using the code below I get the expected results (dest equals input*f(t)), but Visual Leak detector reports a memory leak.

Is there anything wrong with the following code?

```
vector<double> input(10,1.);//input_vector for testing
auto f = [](double t){return sin(t);};

auto fun = [f,input](double t)->vector<double>
{
    vector<double> dest(input.size());
    transform(input.begin(),input.end(),dest.begin(),[=](double a){return a*f(t);});
    return dest;
};
```

If I capture f and t explicitly by writing the line with transform as

```
transform(input.begin(),input.end(),dest.begin(),[f,t](double a){return a*f(t);});
```

Then the snippet does not compile (I get error C3480: a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope).

If I evaluate f outside the transform, and replace the line with the transform by two lines

```
double r = f(t);
transform(input.begin(),input.end(),dest.begin(),[r](double a){return a*r;};
```

I do not get the memory leak. Of course this latter version makes more sense from an efficiency viewpoint because of the single evaluation of f, but I'd like to understand if I'm doing anything illegal in the first version.

Thanks!

Comment: Can your post a report from your tool? I cannot reproduce that behavior on GCC 4.8 with valgrind. BTW, your code snippet is not compilable, it has syntax errors and `ones` is not defined.

Comment: What is `ones`? Maybe it's too small.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it even legal to define a lambda function like you did?

Comment: Appologies for the syntax errors in the snipet, it should be fixed now. 
@Henrik: `ones` was an error and is replaced by `input.size()`.
@user1810087: this is partly my question also; what would be your concerns?

Comment: I experimented a bit (see the updated snippet up top): If I capture the values explicitly in `transform` I get a compiler error. If I capture them implicitly/automatically with `=`, the code compiles.